# String causes geocode to throw error

Tags: r, ggmap, geocode

running this line of code

```
library(ggmap)
geocode(location="Somewhere in Nigeria Winning",source="dsk", output="more")
```

throws this error

```
Error in vapply(gc$results[[1]]$address_components, function(x) x[[nameToGrab]],  : values must be length 1, but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 0
```

can someone shed some light on why this may be happening and what i can do to fix it? i know this seems like an odd question however this string showed up in a set of data to prune and seems to be breaking geocode.

Comment: It's probably because it can't find 'Somewhere in Nigeria Winning" as a location

Comment: For some reason it is the the addition of `output = "more"` which creates an issue for this particular query. `latlon`, `latlona` and `all` work as expected.

Comment: The Data Science Toolkit API went down for a while (it was getting bombarded, I think), and since it came back, it's behaving a little differently. I'm not certain that's what's going on here—nielfws is right; `output = "more` seems buggy—but it may underly the problem.

Comment: If you're trying to parse countries from strings, [I wrote a function for that](https://alistaire47.github.io/passport/reference/parse_country.html) that offers a few options for doing so.

Comment: if it cant find it it returns a zero results string however that particular string seems to kick the code into error land, have to use all kinda inflates my data times but ill give that a shot.

Comment: @alistaire i need the state in the united states so that only gets me halfway

Comment: Since there's only 50 (and change, with DC, PR, etc.) regex isn't too hard. `state.name`/`state.abb` is a a good start, though you'll need to adjust a bit if you can have partial abbreviations like `N. Carolina`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just want to post an answer since i have located the problem, and anyone would like the workaround/want to know what to do. The issue is not with the DSK but with the ggmap code itself. If you run

```
geocode(location="not a place in the slightest",source="dsk", output="more")
```

then the library will fail gracefully and give you back the expected.

```
geocode failed with status ZERO_RESULTS, location = "not a place in the slightest"
```

however with certain strings in the middle like the one above it fails less gracefully because DSK returns data but it isn't good data the issue is caused by the data that sits here in the resulting array (note for obvious reasons you cant get this using the more flag you need to use all).

```
$results[[1]]$address_components[[1]]$long_name
NULL

$results[[1]]$address_components[[1]]$short_name
NULL
```

the code in the lib that parses this into the data frame with the "more" flag chokes here

```
nameToGrab   <- `if`(nameType == "long", "long_name", "short_name")
outputVals  <- vapply(gc$results[[1]]$address_components, function(x)  
x[[nameToGrab]], character(1))
outputNames <- vapply(gc$results[[1]]$address_components, function(x){ if(length(x$types) == 0) return("query")
      x$types[1]
    },
    character(1)
)
```

becasue both long_name and short_name are NULL the vapply is going to fail spectacularly.